# every non empty open set on real line can be written in the DISJOINT countable union of open intervals

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

In point set topology , **this is a well proved statement that every non empty open set on real line can be written in the  DISJOINT countable union of open intervals**[image]

I just taken a open set ( 1 , 10 ) as usual matric space then how can i choose those collection of "COUNTABLE UNION OF DISJOINT OPEN SET "

If I write ( 1 , 5) and ( 5 , 10 ) then 5 isn't in the union . And if i write ( 1 , 5 ] and (5 , 10 ) then it's no more a open set. If i write ( 1 , 5) and (4, 10 ) then it's no mre DISJOINT . Than how it's possible ???

Thanks for always helping me. . .

**[ EDIT : 1 ]**

by @Henno Brandsma and @Stinking Bishop discussion i understand that ( 1 , 10 ) is actually union of singleton set which is its itself .

> But now i am struggling for a non Trivial example in such a way that i take any subset of real line and find a union of countable disjoint interval for it. Because i am sure this theorm is not formed or saying just about trivial cases

Comment: One is countable and a set with one member is trivially pairwise disjoint.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma yeah but i think a set with one member can't be open set specially on real line. Am i right ??

Comment: $(1,10)$ is trivially a union of (one) open set - namely itself. And one-element families count as countable.

Comment: @StinkingBishop yeah trivially it's union of itself. But it's not well intresting if i do so. And on real line , how can a singleton set be open because if i choose any $\epsilon$ , no open ball come in that singleton set .

Comment: Singletons are never open in the usual metric on thé reals

Comment: We are not talking about a singleton set $\{a\}$ where $a$ is a *real number*. However, $\{(1, 10)\}$ *is* a singleton (family/collection of sets). And it is disjoint as well (!). Maybe that is where the confusion is coming from. And, yes, it is not very interesting, but the article above never promised it had to be interesting in all cases!

Comment: then , on real line how can we understand this theorem by taking a better example ( non trivial case )

Comment: The open set $(-\infty, 0)\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{n+1}, \frac{1}{n}\right)\bigcup (1,\infty)$ anyone?

Comment: @StinkingBishop i was just reviewing this example , where is " 1 " in this whole union ??

Comment: It's not in the set. The set is precisely the complement of $\{0\}\cup\{\frac{1}{n}\mid n\in\mathbb N\}$ (which is closed in $\mathbb R$).

Comment: Thanks , @StinkingBishop for providing me this opportunity again of asking my doubts. I searched about cantor one third set and found a collection of closed sets. But how this is answer of my question . You can even give the " answer " so that at last i will close the question

Comment: You need to recall how Cantor's set is created. First, take the interval $[0,1]$, i.e. remove $(-\infty, 0)$ and $(1,\infty)$ from $\mathbb R$. Then, remove the middle third $(1/3, 2/3)$. Then, remove the middle thirds in the two remaining intervals: $(1/9, 2/9)$ and $(7/9, 8/9)$. Then, remove the middle thirds in the four remaining intervals, etc. What's lef is a *closed* set (Cantor's set), and what's *removed* is the open set (the complement of Cantor's set) - which is now obviously a union of open intervals, namely those that we removed in the previous procedure.

Comment: So, to avoid any doubt, it is not the Cantor's set that can be seen as a union of open intervals: it is its *complement*.

Comment: @StinkingBishop thanks now it's totally understood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement simply means if $\mathcal{G}$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}$ then $\mathcal{G}$ can be written as a union of the members of $\mathcal {F}= \{\mathcal{O} : \mathcal{O} \text{ is an open interval in } \mathbb{R} \}$ where:

- $\mathcal{F}$ is countable.
- $\mathcal{F}$ is pairwise disjoint, which means any two distinct open intervals $\mathcal{O}$ and $\mathcal{O}'$ in $\mathcal{F}$ are disjoint.

and hence $\mathcal{G}= \bigcup\limits_{\mathcal{O} \in \mathcal{F}} \mathcal{O}$

In case of $\mathcal{G}= (1,10)$, your $\mathcal{F}$ is simply the set $ \mathcal{F}=\{(1,10) \}$. Notice that $\mathcal{F}$ is indeed a countable set of pairwise disjoint open intervals [vacuously](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth), whose union is $\mathcal{G}$.

Comment: Yeah thanks Ibrahim

Comment: @user926846 If this answers your question then you may [*accept*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234) it.

Comment: actually i am still struggling for a non Trivial example .